# How to preserve line breaks in text content de-identified with Data Loss Prevention?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dlp

I am using an API call [`content.deidentify`](https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.content/deidentify) to de-identify text content. It is working as expected, but newline characters get stripped.

**API call**

```
curl -s \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  https://dlp.googleapis.com/v2/projects/$PROJECT_ID/content:deidentify \
  -d @text-request.json \
  > text-response.json
```

**Input**

```
Eleanor Rigby 
Pharmacist 
Liverpool Hospital 
eleanor.rigby@example.com
```

**Output**

```
{
  "item": {
    "value": "Eleanor Rigby Pharmacist Liverpool Hospital [email-address]"
  },
  "overview": {
    ...
  }
}
```

Is there any option I can add to the request to preserve the line breaks?

I found [`setPrettyPrint`](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/dlp/v2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/dlp/v2/DLPRequest.html#setPrettyPrint-java.lang.Boolean-) in the Java client documentation. Can I use this option when calling the API directly?

Comment: Can you detail how you call the API today and how do you print the result?

Comment: And how is formatted your item value in the request?

Comment: It was malformed, because of the newline characters.

Comment: Ok, so you removed the newline in the request JSON, and it's normal to not have them in output. You can replace the line return by the \n character. It is kept in output and therefore, you can use it to pretty print your output.

Comment: Sure, I did that. I described it in my answer below. It contains the malformed JSON I was sending in the request.

Comment: Sorry I didn't read!! So it's solved!! Perfect!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue had nothing to do with DLP.

I was sending **invalid JSON**:

```
{
    "item": {
        "value": "Eleanor Rigby 
Pharmacist 
Liverpool Hospital 
eleanor.rigby@example.com"
    },
    "deidentifyConfig": {
        ...
    }
}
```

Replacing the newline characters with `\n` solved the problem.